# iPhone App Crashes in Main

Tags: iphone, objective-c, crash, program-entry-point

It crashes in the main function at the line:

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

here's the debug output:

```
#0  0x33bd52d4 in __kill
#1  0x33bd52ca in kill
#2  0x33bd52bc in raise
#3  0x33be9d78 in abort
#4  0x31bdba26 in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler
#5  0x3347c59a in _objc_terminate
#6  0x31bd9df8 in __cxxabiv1::__terminate
#7  0x31bd9e4c in std::terminate
#8  0x31bd9f1c in __cxa_throw
#9  0x3347b4ca in objc_exception_throw
#10 0x33ac0704 in -[NSException raise]
#11 0x3367db4e in -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forUndefinedKey:]
#12 0x3367d03a in _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter
#13 0x3367eda2 in -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:]
#14 0x33630b16 in -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:]
#15 0x3224c60e in -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect]
#16 0x33a63fc6 in -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:]
#17 0x33a6cd50 in -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:]
#18 0x3224b576 in -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:]
#19 0x3224cb38 in -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:]
#20 0x3209e870 in -[UIApplication _loadMainNibFile]
#21 0x3209a1fc in -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:]
#22 0x3206648a in -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:]
#23 0x32065ec8 in -[UIApplication sendEvent:]
#24 0x32065906 in _UIApplicationHandleEvent
#25 0x33b0ef02 in PurpleEventCallback
#26 0x33a556fe in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
#27 0x33a556c2 in __CFRunLoopDoSource1
#28 0x33a47f7c in __CFRunLoopRun
#29 0x33a47c86 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific
#30 0x33a47b8e in CFRunLoopRunInMode
#31 0x32099308 in -[UIApplication _run]
#32 0x32096e92 in UIApplicationMain
#33 0x0000288a in main at main.m:14
```

can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: (Almost) every crash happens with `UIApplicationMain` at the bottom of the call stack because your main thread spends all its time in that method or its descendants. But that's not what you are looking for. Your app crashes while loading your app's main NIB file (note `_loadMainNibFile`), probably because you have made a wrong connection in Interface Builder. What exception/error message do you get in the console?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the stack trace it seems that the app fails when loading it's main NIB file.

In this case the full exception message will probably end up in the console too. That should give you a clue to what goes wrong. Post it here if you need help with that.

Comment: it was just because I deleted an IBOutlet in Xcode and forgot to remove the connection in IB.. how silly. Won't be making that mistake again.. thanks for the answer, cheers